# Prevent NavController to destroy a fragment on "navigate"

Tags: android

I have two fragments **FragmentMap** and **FragmentPoiDialog**

In the "FragmentMap" I am using the following code, to navigate to "FragmentPoiDialog"

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable(fragment_poidialog.ARG_PARAM1Poi, p);
args.putParcelable(fragment_poidialog.ARG_PARAM2LatLang, latLng);
Navigation.findNavController(getView()).navigate(R.id.action_fragment_maps_to_poiDialog, args);
```

At the moment when navigate is called - I see the "FragmentMap.onDestroyView" triggered.

**Questions:**

- I understand, that the fragment is destroyed when I navigate away from it. Where can I find the documentation, about the impact of navigationController navigation - on the fragments?
- Is it possible to navigate away from the fragment, without destroying it, with the help of NavigatorController?

Comment: The fragment isn't destroyed - you'd get a callback to `onDestroy()` if that was the case.

Comment: OK, that means only the GoogleMap associated with the fragment is destroyed, when I navigate away? So I need to update the references to the view, when navigating back?